# How to parse an html table with a fixed shape?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table, python-requests

I receive an html table that have always the same shape. Only the values differ in each time.

```
html = '''
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td>NAME A</td>
        <th>Status</th>
        <td class="IN PROGRESS">IN PROGRESS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <td COLSPAN="3">CATEGORY A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Creation date</th>
        <td>13/01/23 23:00</td>
        <th>End date</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
'''
```

I need to convert it to a dataframe but pandas is giving me a weird format :

```
print(pd.read_html(html)[0])

               0               1           2            3
0           Name          NAME A      Status  IN PROGRESS
1       Category      CATEGORY A  CATEGORY A   CATEGORY A
2  Creation date  13/01/23 23:00    End date          NaN
```

I feel like we need to use beautifulsoup but I'm not sure how :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

Can you guys help me with that ?

My expected output is this dataframe :

```
     Name    Category   Status     Creation date  End date
0  NAME A  CATEGORY A  RUNNING  27/07/2023 11:43       NaN
```

Comment: It's strange to have `<th>` and `<td>` elements mixed in the same row.  The usual practice is to have one row with all the `<th>` headers, and the remaining rows are all `<td>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example you could iterate the `<td>`´s and store its text with its previous sibling `<th>` in a `dict` and create your `dataframe`:

```
{e.find_previous_sibling('th').text:e.text for e in soup.select('table td')}
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html = '''
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td>NAME A</td>
        <th>Status</th>
        <td class="IN PROGRESS">IN PROGRESS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <td COLSPAN="3">CATEGORY A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Creation date</th>
        <td>13/01/23 23:00</td>
        <th>End date</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {e.find_previous_sibling('th').text:e.text for e in soup.select('table td')}
    ]
)
```

###### Result

|  | Name | Status | Category | Creation date | End date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NAME A | IN PROGRESS | CATEGORY A | 13/01/23 23:00 |  |

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in pandas too:

```
df=pd.read_html(io.StringIO(html))[0]
df=pd.concat([df[[0,1]],df[[2,3]].rename(columns={2:0,3:1})]).T
df=pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[1].to_list()],columns=df.iloc[0])
```